# Is it possible to display a table in skype from bot framework?

Tags: bots, botframework

I'm building a chatbot with MS bot framework and i've found that the text displayed by the bot is defaulted to be interpretated as markdown.

Here is the markdown:

```
#### Chris Butler Ltd
* A Point
* A Point

|Name|Value|
|---|---:|
|Status|Active|
|Balance|£0.00|
|Credit Limit|£0.00|
|Available Credit|£0.00|
```

The emulator displays a markdown table perfectly

[image: Markdown Table in Emulator]

When you view it in skype:

[image]

I'm surprised to see that skype has actually added some hyphens (-)!

Does anyone know how to display the table so that skype understands it as a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have displayed is actually how skype interprets markdown tables:
https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/channel-inspector/channels/Skype?f=Markdown&e=example1

> Tables: If you are communicating with a channel which supports fixed
>   width fonts or HTML you can use standard table markdown, but because
>   many channels (such as SMS) do not have a known display width and/or
>   have variable width fonts it is not possible to render a table
>   properly on all channels.

So, in answer to your question:

> Does anyone know how to display the table so that skype understands
>   it as a table?

What you have is correct, and skype is already interpreting it as a table.  Skype just doesn't do a very good job of it.

---

On a related note: there's also a TextFormat property on the reply object, that can be set to xml (Skype Only)  see here: https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/activities.html#textformat This will not fix the table issue you're experiencing either, but might provide more options.

Comment: Though the question is for Skype, just wanted to record this here for anyone looking for similar answer for Skype for Business...Send you HTML formatted table to Skype for Business and it displays it beautifully